# Mass deleting local branches that has been rebased and merged

Tags: git, github

in our team we keep the **fast-forward only** merge policy for master and development branches in order to prevent *merge commit hell*:

[image: merge commit hell]

I do not delete my topic branches once they are merged (or rebased and then merged), so I end up with tons of these. I can delete some:

```
git branch --merged
```

This will only show me those which hasn't been rebased prior merge. And there are some of these, I am able to clean them up.

I am looking for some strategy, script or hint how to deal with *the rebased ones*. There must be a script that finds all the commits from the topic branch in the master in a loop or something. Please share ;-)

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the `fast-forward` merged branches? Just to be sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, I mean that: git merge --ff-only

Comment: Actually `git branch --merged` should show you all branches which are fully contained by `HEAD`, this is valid for fast-forwarded branches and merged branches. I'm not sure I understand the issue correctly.

Comment: I forgot to menion that the one who merges the change rebases it, so I don't have the rebased version locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [one script](https://gist.github.com/antonio/4586646) which does that by:

- getting the last commit of each branch
- checking that commit is part of the history of master

That would delete rebased branches which have been merged to master.

```
last_commit_msg="$(git log --oneline --format=%f -1 $branch)"
if [[ "$(git log --oneline --format=%f | grep $last_commit_msg | wc -l)" -eq 1 ]]; then
```

Comment: I extended your example a bit into interactive tool, see my answer here. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 13):

I wanted something non-interactive that generalizes to more than one commit per branch.  With the caveat that this hasn't been tested extensively yet, and may be assuming more than you do about the state of your clone when you run this:

Rebase all local branches that can be rebased cleanly:

```
REBASE_TARGET=upstream/master
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads/); do
    git rebase "$REBASE_TARGET" "$branch" || git rebase --abort
done
```

Remove any local branches that have been merged:

```
git branch --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" --merged | xargs git branch -d
```

Comment: Such an excellent idea. This got rid of a good number of the branches, and to me this was a quite safe an easy way to do so. Now I can use some other method (like checking subjects) to check the remaining ones.

Comment: Very elegant and just what I was looking for. One adjustment for me, swapping `upstream/master` for `origin/master`.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an interactive script that can help with this.

https://github.com/lzap/git-xcleaner

Send patches and read the warning from it's manual page (bellow)!

[image: git xcleaner main menu]

> git-xcleaner(1) -- interactive git branch removal SYNOPSIS
>
> git xcleaner
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This tool helps with deleting unused topic branches using TUI (text
>   user interface). It also offers mechanisms for pre-selecting branches
>   that can be safely removed.
>
> WARNING
>
> This tool deletes git branches after confirmation. There is no way
>   back when git garbage is collected. Double check what you are about to
>   remove!
>
> RETURN VALUES
>
> Zero on success, one on errors when manipulating with git.
>
> BUGS
>
> File bugs at https://github.com/lzap/git-xcleaner/issues