# Delete all local branches that have been squashed and merged

Tags: git, github

I am working on a fork of a repository.
I send pull requests from branches of that fork and they get "Squash and Merged"  into the master branch of the upstream repository once they are accepted.
How can I automatically find and delete local branches that have already been squashed and merged? Most strategies shown in [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800387/mass-deleting-local-branches-that-has-been-rebased-and-merged) rely on determining whether all commits in a branch can be found in master's commit history, but since all my commits are squashed this condition is never met.

#### More Info

My `git remote -v` looks like:

```sh
origin  git@github.com:sshleifer/transformers_fork.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:sshleifer/transformers_fork.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:huggingface/transformers.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:huggingface/transformers.git (push)
```

Comment: Yes, well, that is one price to pay for squashing: a squash is not a merge (despite the name) and so the history is lost. So what is the question? You can still delete the branch.

Comment: edited for clarity: question is "How can I automatically find and delete local branches that have already been squashed and merged?"

Comment: Yes, I thought you might have meant that. :) You should get an email informing you of the PR having been accepted. I just delete after that.

Comment: If it was merged in the recent past, you could go over your branches, merging master into them, and checking whether the diff with master is empty. That can be done programmatically. If there were conflicts, you could check that the diff with HEAD is equal to the diff with master. This gets less and less reliable the more you've diverged from master.

Answer (score 4):

Through git alone : the short answer is you can't (not with 100% reliability).

Here are some unreliable ways to explore :

- if the commit messages on master contain the branch name : grep it out ;
- if the commit messages on master contain a PR name : grep it out, then use Github's api to find what branch is linked to this PR ;
- if the commit messages on master contain an issue number : grep it out, and match it with your own rule (issue number in branch name ? `fix #xyz` in some commit message ?) ;
- if the branches are always merged soon enough, or rebased on master before being squashed + merged, you can try to look if the *content* (the `^{tree}`) in your branch matches the content of a commit on master :

  - `git log --first-parent --format="%T"` will give you the list of trees on master,
  - `git rev-parse branch/name^{tree}` will give you the tree for branch `branch/name`

Comment: I found a reasonable heuristic: can the local branch be rebased cleanly. Now need to figure out how to delete all branches that have the same HEAD commit as master.

Comment: `git rev-parse branch` should be equal to `git rev-parse master`

Answer (score 0):

If you can persuade the owners of the upstream repository, you could use a workflow where instead of generating pull requests from the fork to some long-lived branch of the upstream, you instead generate pull requests against a short-lived feature branch that has the exact same name as the branch you are pushing, and then separately the administrator can manage a pull request from that feature branch (in the upstream) to the long-lived branch. If this deletes the feature branch upon the squash merge, then you could detect when upstream feature branches are deleted with `remote prune`.

```
# My PR to upstream creates a new feature branch
fork:my-feature-branch -> upstream:my-feature-branch

# Upstream deals with merging to long-lived branch
# this operation will delete upstream:my-feature-branch
upstream:my-feature-branch -> upstream:develop

# I synchronize my fork with upstream and observe branches removed
# with remote prune, and either manually or programmatically delete
# the fork: version of those branches.
```